# MySQL Connection code needs fixing. I hit a dead end

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection

I'm currently working on a custom admin panel for a DayZ server, which will run on a local computer & connect to a remote database. I've Google'd more than ever, but I've hit a dead end. I can't seem to find a fix for this code which I've found & been told that it should work.

```
Public Function sqlConnect(ByVal server, port, instance, uname, pword) As Boolean
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    connection = New SqlConnection()
    connection.ConnectionString = "Server=" & server & port & "; Uid=" & uname & "; Pwd=" & pword & "; Database=***;"
    Try
        connection.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened Successfully")
        Return True
        connection.Close()
    Catch mysql_error As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database: " & mysql_error.Message)
        Return False
    Finally
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

If anyone here could help me out in finding the solution as to how I can get onto that MySQL server, you'ld be forever in my debt.

Notes: I'm using VS 2012 express, programming this exclusively in VB.NET, because it's quite a big project (for me) and it's the language I know best. Any add-ons required can be downloaded, as long as other users won't have to download it aswell.

I've never used a MySQL database before, so I might just be doing something completely wrong.

EDIT: The information that is given beforehand contains:
server ip, port, database ID, username & password.

[image: mysql_error.Message]

Comment: Add the error (mysql_error.Message) to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't connect to `MySQL` using `SqlConnection` class. It is designed to connect to MS SQL Server. Try use **[this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)**

Comment: I've tried that software, but for some reason I still can't use `imports MySQL.*`

Answer (score 0):

Found it, this code works perfectly:

```
Public Function sqlConnect(ByVal server, port, instance, uname, pword) As Boolean
    Dim connection As MySqlConnection
    connection = New MySqlConnection()
    connection.ConnectionString = "Host=" & server & ";port=" & port & _
 ";user=" & uname & ";password=" & pword & ";"
    Try
        connection.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened Successfully")
        Return True
        connection.Close()
    Catch mysql_error As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database: " & mysql_error.Message)
        Return False
    Finally
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```